# Pendrive formatting to ext4/LUKS problem

Tags: 16.04, mount, encryption, usb-drive, luks

I've just mount new pendrive with msdos fs on it, and i tried formatting it to Luks/Ext4.

How i tried :
Files -> right click on penrive -> format.. :
Erase : Overwrite existing data with zeros
Type : Encrypted, compatible with Linux systems (Luks + Ext4)
And i've chosen ext4/LUKS
Then i gave passphrase and clicked start format.

After that i had no information, nor progress bar etc.
and each time i tried (many hours) waiting with hope formatting is ended, after pluging it off  i get such an error :

Error formatting volume:
Error erasing cleartext device: Error writing 1048576 bytes to /dev/dm-4: Input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0)

How can i know when to plug off pendrive and how to see progress of fragmentation when pendrive is getting unvisible ? I'm running 16.04 LTS

Comment: Which program are you running when you right click?

Comment: Default one from GUI : Files -> right click on penrive -> format.. -> "Format Volume"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the progress by loading **Gnome-disk**.

Nautilus is the default File browser.  It doesn't show any status of activity as you described.  I tested an encryption on a 8gig partition using the `zero's` overwrite.  It took about 20 minutes.  Without the `zeros` it take seconds.

You can see a status of the disk availability by loading `gnome-disk`.

The `gnome-disk` GUI will give you a status of all your drives and partitions.  Select the partition you are formatting and you'll see a progress bar of what is happening with the drive.